# What can cause a window to just shatter?

Tags: power-windows

While turning a corner [a left] my back driver's side window shattered and filled the back seat with bits of glass.  As near as I can tell it all fell in.  I can not see a rock amongst the debris.  A BB or pellet may be there as they are small and I have not cleaned up the entire mess yet.  Barring a misbehaving child, is there something in a power window system that can under rare conditions cause a window to shatter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there was a weakness or chip, the slight bending placed on a pane of glass by turning could be enough to shatter it. When you turn a corner in any car there is flex in the chassis - usually this wouldn't be enough to cause any problems though, as there is rubber holding the window in place and this should flex enough, so I can only assume something had already weakened the glass.

Of course the simpler alternative is a BB or pellet, as you mention - and one could even have done the damage and bounced so may not be discovered.

Comment: There may also have been an existing crack or weakness in the glass that you hadn't noticed before

Comment: @Nick - yep, that's why I mensioned it in the first 7 words of my answer :-)

Comment: oops - I must read more closely!